# Adding endpoint for grafana simple json plugin?

Tags: angular, plugins, grafana

I'm using the grafana-simple-json-datasource with Python it's working fine, however I want to add a brand new endpoint, but no matter I try, nothing is working.

Here are natives endpoints

```
/ should return 200 ok. Used for "Test connection" on the datasource config page.
/search used by the find metric options on the query tab in panels.
/query should return metrics based on input.
/annotations should return annotations.
/tag-keys should return tag keys for ad hoc filters.
/tag-values should return tag values for ad hoc filters.
```

I want to add for example /secondaryQuery which comes after selected /query.

I tried to duplicate and modify the existing function "metricFindQuery(query)" but it seems that it's not that

Comment: What is the purpose of your secondary query? If you just want another time series, I think you would do that when setting up the datasource. It looks like you can add many queries when setting up the data source, each with its own target and type.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, I solved this long time ago and I'm sure about the solution I used.
I think that when I post this question I was modifying /src directory without building it with npm (and /dist is used instead of /src so all my changes were not effective)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because I was modifying /src directory without building it with npm (and /dist is used instead of /src). So all my changes were not effective.